# Cannot save payment methods in Magento 2.26

Tags: magento2

Cannot save payment methods in Magento 2.26. When I click on "save" nothing happens. Any idea?

Comment: Please check Magento log files for some clue.

Comment: Also, check javascript error at your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Store View -Select Default Store View then Save. Sometimes, It will work.